# What is the Ember way of converting retrieved Ember Data records into plain objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have retrieved a series of records using `var items = store.find('model');`. The returned object is an instance of `RecordArray`, and contains several entries, each with an Ember object that allows me to get and set properties into the records.

It all looks pretty good.

Now I need to feed the returned objects into a third party library, and of course I cannot send Ember objects there since it expects plain objects.

I looked on pages and pages of related material but I can't find any generic way of doing this. I'm pretty sure there is one since this seems to be a very basic use case, so I don't 
want to reinvent the wheel and write it all again.

Is there a facility in Ember for that? How can I obtain a simple array with plain JavaScript objects (just hashes, I mean) from this `RecordArray` I got?

**UPDATE**

Of course I can do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(recordArray));` but for large objects that doesn't seem too performant with so many conversions. I'm wondering if Ember provides a more direct way (with better performance) of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no ObjectSerializer so probably easiest way is to use JSONSerializer and use JSON.parse to create objects out of them.

```
items.map(function(e){
  return JSON.parse(e.toJSON());
});
```

However, you can manually write serialization logic.

```
function serializeToObject(model){
  var fields = Ember.get(model.constructor, 'fields');
  obj = {};
  fields.forEach(function(fieldName, kindOfField){
    obj[fieldName] = model.get(fieldName);
  });
  return obj;
}
```